# Sending different values to API than stored in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, ios, post, nsuserdefaults

I have an app in the App Store that uses geofences to post updates to our local API. To date, this has been a smashing success. A couple months ago I installed Flurry to get some insight into customer usage and any unhandled exceptions out there. What I started getting back were some errors pertaining to the saved token we use to authenticate the user id.

This token is an MD5 salted hash of the username and password. No issues here, we use it for everything in the app. I store it in the NSUserDefaults and retrieve it before every API call. As we started narrowing down our search for the culprit, it is showing that we are sending a token that doesn't exist anywhere on our servers. When the user trips a geofence, it updates their status automatically, but a very small percent has been failing in the background causing some customer concerns.

Sorry for the long precursor, on to the question. What would cause my value in NSUserDefaults to get loaded to an NSString differently from one time to the next? I have tested the logic, it will update me 3 times in a row when I show up for work, but the 4th, I'll get a token failure error back from the server. There is no rhyme or reason to why it fails. Our server is logging these failed tokens and we can't match them up to anything.

So if anyone has any insight on this matter, I would very much appreciate it. Could it be messing up when I store it to NSString? Could it be some inconsistencies with my POST method? It might even be on our server, I dunno. I'm hoping everyone on SO can lend a hand and help me get some new insight. Thanks in advance.

```
//Loading the token... done this way for EVERY API call
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *token = [defaults objectForKey:@"token"];
```

Code taken from my API class

```
//My POST method for updating our API
NSString *requestData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?auth_token=%@", token];
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestData UTF8String] length: [requestData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/user.json%@", webAddress, requestData]]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *payloadData = [json JSONValue];

if([[payloadData objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue]) {
   // if i get here, successful update
} else {
   // update unsuccessful, error message returned... bad token
}
```

Comment: A few things come to mind...but remember I have limited experience :)

Is it possible that you're entering this routine while the routine hasn't finished before?  I saw this in ControlPlane with growl messaging where the pointers were being clobbered and double freed.  A couple of things to try here.  Store the token in a static var and set it only an app launch OR if they change their password.  Another option is to lock while doing an API call.  It might be anyone of those variables.

Comment: It is weird because it works "most" of the time. And it is sending a token, just not one that works. The only other hashes I use are for gravatar images, but can't image NSString *token is getting stepped on by gravatar in other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want this question to linger out there and waste anyone's time or energy. After some recent testing, I don't believe my issue is with the user defaults or the saved token. There are already answers out there, so I can't delete the question. So I'll just leave a small answer here and close it out.

I ended up moving all the login credentials to the iOS keychain. I salt and hash the email and password each time I need an API token. It creates a little more overhead for each API, but knowing my users' credentials are safe and secure is probably worth it. I still have my issue, but I think I'm getting closer to nailing it down. Thank you to anyone that has looked at my question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any 3rd party libraries?  "token" is a very common string, I would change it to something else.  It's possible some other code is stomping on your token with their token.

Comment: Agreed. You should **always** give your NSUserDefaults longer names, e.g. `@"MyAppAPIToken"`

Comment: The only other code that might step on toes is the SBJsonKit. I don't believe anything else is storing to the user defaults. I'll try extending the name some and see if that helps.

Comment: Do I understand that right, if I save "token" to user defaults and another application or system preference saves to "token", it will get overwritten?

Comment: Unless you tell it otherwise, the information is stored in a plist that is named the same as your bundle identifier.  No other (properly written) application should write to it.  This is how it works under OS X anyway. As mentioned, it is possible for a 3rd party lib/framework to also write to the same file since it is running under the context of your app.

Comment: Ok, that is what I was operating under. Thanks for the clarification.